# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with items of different size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have an `UICollectionView` where the items can modify at run time it's height.
The problem is that when an item is higher than another, the item are surrounded by a lot o blank space.

[image]

I'm looking for a property that create this:

[image]

and I want use `UICollectionView` not github example or third part implementation.
Thanks.

Comment: this is not possible just using standard UICollectionView... you can either mess with the code on your own or try one of the third party options http://www.binpress.com/app/pinterest-gridview-for-ios-masonryview/836 is a good example of something free that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` behaves this way. Try to reload your collection view after modifying the height or returning a different value for that cell in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` and see if the gap fills. Otherwise, I'd recommend using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

This class might fit this purpose properly - a UICollectionViewLayout subclass to work with your collection view:
https://github.com/aceisScope/WaterflowView/blob/master/WaterFlowDisplay/WaterFlowLayout.h